# Ideas on how to convert a JSON message to ASN.1

Tags: json, python-3.x, network-programming, asn.1

I am trying to convert a JSON message to ASN.1. My goal is to convert JSON (captured from wire-shark) to ASN.1 and then, convert asn1 to 802.11p. Any ideas or resources I should look into?  I am using Python 3.7.

Comment: I would advice to add some code into your question. It will increase the chances of receiving help and reduce the chances to have the question flagged and closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest two possible solutions:

1. Compile the ASN.1 schema with [asn1c](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c), it does not support JSON but does support XER/XML format, so you will need to convert the JSON to the XML/XER format expected by the asn1c and then convert the XER message to binary using the converter-example that is generaged by asn1c. Wireshark could export in XML format as well but this XML would have different structure than the one supported by asn1c (XER) so you will need to convert it.
2. You could export the data in `jsonraw` format and then extract the `*_raw` field of the protocol you are interested in. This way you don't have to convert JSON to ASN.1 to `binary` as you get `binary` directly from the JSON as a HEX string.

```
$ tshark -T jsonraw -j "incorrect" -r test_capture.pcap
[
  {
    "_index": "packets-2019-04-17",
    "_type": "pcap_file",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "layers": {
        "frame_raw": ["02112233445502778899aabb08004500003cc8c1400040060fcfac100501ac10050ac01a20fbcfc1fd2f00000000a00272108f2e0000020405b40402080a00a035ee0000000001030307", 0, 74, 0, 1],
        "frame": {
          "filtered": "frame"
        },
        "eth_raw": ["02112233445502778899aabb0800", 0, 14, 0, 1],
        "eth": {
          "filtered": "eth"
        },
        "ip_raw": ["4500003cc8c1400040060fcfac100501ac10050a", 14, 20, 0, 1],
        "ip": {
          "filtered": "ip"
        },
        "tcp_raw": ["c01a20fbcfc1fd2f00000000a00272108f2e0000020405b40402080a00a035ee0000000001030307", 34, 40, 0, 1],
        "tcp": {
          "filtered": "tcp"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert JSON to ASN.1 using this tool https://asn1.io/json2asn/. Keep in mind that converting a message (JSON) into a schema (ASN.1) is always an approximation (e.g. it's impossible to tell if `"signal":3` corresponds to an `INTEGER` type or an `ENUMERATION` type), hence you'll have to review and refine the generated schema or try to convert more than a single message. Once you have ASN.1 schema there are variety of ASN.1 tools for your particular language.

On the other hand, if you are working with a protocol that is well known and you're not looking to customize it (or the data) you may be able to find the original ASN.1 schema from the protocol publisher.

Answer (score 1):

May be you could try your luck with [pyasn1 "native" codec](http://snmplabs.com/pyasn1/pyasn1/codec/native/contents.html)...

The workflow could be to:

1. Turn JSON into Python types, then
2. Feed them to "native" pyasn1 decoder, which would produce [py]ASN.1 data structures (not ASN.1 text though)
3. Then you could pass these data structures to pyasn1 BER encoder to turn them into BER (if that's what you ultimately need)