# How convert asn1 to JSON

Tags: json, influxdb, asn.1

How can I convert (decode) incoming ASN.1 messages (UPER) to JSON? It would be great to use any Telegraf plugin since my goal is to inject it to InfluxDB directly.

I've seen this post [Ideas on how to convert a JSON message to ASN.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55714024/ideas-on-how-to-convert-a-json-message-to-asn-1) , but I want the opposite

Answer (score 1):

To decode a message (UPER is just one of ASN.1 encoding formats) you will need a schema for your message. Then search for an ASN.1 toolkit that supports UPER and JER (JER is ASN.1 format to represent messages in JSON). Using the toolkit, compile the schema to get the data bindings (structures to hold your message) in your programming language of choice, then invoke the codec API to decode from UPER (into the bindings), re-encode into JER (from the bindings).

Comment: I'm trying this package from python https://pypi.org/project/asn1tools/ , however, no exit. Here is what I've tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65310344/how-decode-asn1-hex-value-using-asn1tools

Comment: That asn1tools project documentation says it doesn't support CLASS etc..  A lot of modern specs use that syntax.  You should check your spec to see if it uses syntax supported by the tool you are trying.  There are also commercial tools, such as from my company (www.obj-sys.com).