# How decode asn1 hex value using asn1tools

Tags: python, json, udp, converters, asn.1

I'm trying to decode the following ASN1 message using Python

```
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x89G\x11\x00\x1a\x01\x00\x10\x00\x80\x00\x00\x01\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x98c\xc7h\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

This is my code:

```
import asn1tools
import socket
import sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_address = ('239.118.122.97', 8947)
#server_address = ('localhost', 8947)
#server_address = ('192.168.1.63', 8948)
#server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 8947)
print('starting up on {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.bind(server_address)

while True:
    print('\nwaiting to receive message')
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(8947)

    print('\nreceived {} bytes from {}'.format(
        len(data), address))
    print(data)
    foo = asn1tools.compile_files(data,'uper')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "udp.py", line 21, in <module>
    foo = asn1tools.compile_files(data,'uper')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asn1tools/compiler.py", line 376, in compile_files
    return compile_dict(parse_files(filenames, encoding),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/asn1tools/parser.py", line 1877, in parse_files
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding=encoding, errors='replace') as fin:
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I expect a JSON format message.

Comment: looking for this ... anything found ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the documentation indicates that compile_files is for compiling the ASN specification (looks like it takes a file name).  You appear to be trying to use it on the encoded data.

Comment: I've tried also `f = asn1tools convert -i uper -o jer data` but I couln't run it successfully

Comment: You need to figure out how to feed the ASN specification to your tool.  PER data can't be decoded without reference to the specification.

Answer (score 0):

> if var b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x89G\x11\x00\x1a\x01\x00\x10\x00\x80\x00\x00\x01\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x98c\xc7h\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

```
decoded_var=var.hex()
```